# Laravel is changing my route

Tags: php, laravel, post

I am making a permissions sytem with Sentinel and I have it so that the user can edit the permissions,

```
Route::get('assign/{id}', function($id){

    $user = Sentinel::findById($id);

    $permisos = array_keys($user['permissions']);

    return view('assign',['permisos' => $permisos, 'id' => $id]);
});
```

thats the route it is used to acces the edit then in there there is a form with

```
<form action=<?php echo "/assign/" . $id; ?> method="POST">
```

and then there is other routw to access the controller

```
Route::post('assign/{id}', ['as' => 'id', 'uses' =>'permissionsController@assign']);
```

but when I tried to access it somehow it transforms my url into assign.{id} 
giviving me this error

```
View [assign.{id}] not found.
```

any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
{!!Form::model($your,['route' => ['assign',$your->id], 'method' => 'put' ])!!}
```

here $your getting from your controller edit view method... something like this

```
public function examole($id){
    $your = Model::findOrfail($id);
    return view('your edit view',compact('your'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am using laravel 5 and it does not suppor forms anymore